# How do I "add" time to firebase timestamp in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question is best stated in an example:

It is currently 9:00am. User wants to do activity at 4:00pm the following day. They use UIDatePicker to select 4:00pm the next day, and then hit a button. I know firebase does times in milliseconds from 1970, so what I want to do is "add" the number of milliseconds from 9:00am to 4:00pm the following day to the `ServerValue.timestamp()`, like so:

```
 activitiesRef.child(newActivity.id).setValue([ 
    "id": newActivity.id,
    "name": newActivity.name,
    "isActive": newActivity.isActive,
    "locString": newActivity.locationString,
    "locLat": newActivity.locLat,
    "locLong": newActivity.locLong,
    "privacySetting": newActivity.privacySetting,
    "targetTime": ServerValue.timestamp()]) // + some added value of time
    //"targetTime": [".sv": "timestamp"]])
```

The reason for this is because I will be displaying a countdown timer elsewhere in the app until it reaches the targetTime. If I can push to firebase the targetTime, then the countdown timer will be a simple comparison of the current time on the user's phone to the targetTime itself.

The error I keep getting when trying to add a double value to the ServerValue.timestamp() is "Contextual type 'Any' cannot be used with dictionary literal"

If it is not possible to do so, what other options do I have? Thank you.

Comment: Consisely, how do I add milliseconds to the ServerValue.timestamp()?

Answer (score 0):

ServerValue.timestamp() is not a number that you can use to perform date arithmetic.  It's a special placeholder value that the server side interprets with its sense of time.

The best you can do is write the timestamp, read it back out as a number, then perform math on it.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of doing this. This is a brilliant workaround in my opinion. I will try this and let you know!